# Whys is dllhost (COM Surrogate) consuming almost all of my memory?

Tags: windows-7, memory

On Windows 7, at any given point and for no apparent reason, my computer starts to slow down until I can no longer open applications such as Photoshop and windows starts to function incorrectly.

If I check the running processes with the task manager, there is clearly the dllhost process consuming almost all available RAM.

**Image:**
[image]

I can stop the process myself manually but that I think it is not the most sophisticated solution. My copy of Windows is up to date with recommended and optional security updates as of January 2014 and my antivirus program shows there are no threats of any kind on my computer.

Any solution to this?

Comment: Is that `Memory` display the private working set? It's truncated in the image. Does this correlate with opening folders with videos in them? Trying to display a preview of a corrupt `mp4` can cause this.

Comment: Yes, it displays Private working set

Comment: Use ProcessExplorer and hover over the DLLhost.exe with the mouse and now yo get a tooltip and which DLL is loaded.

Comment: any update on that issue?